# React: Mapping data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to map data that I have in an array, however, the data is not mapped when I run the code. If I log the data (serials variable), it logs the variables that I would like to map (screenshot below). Does anyone have any suggestions about why the data isn't mapped?

```
numberList() {
  const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serials");
    
    serialRef.on("value", (serial_numbers)=> {
      const serials = [];
      serial_numbers.forEach((serial_number)=> {
        serials.push({s:serial_number.val()});
      });
      console.log(serials);
  return (
    <div>
      {serials.map((number) => <Card>
      <Card.Body>{number.s.serial}</Card.Body> </Card>)}
    </div>
  );
    });

}
        render (){
        return (
          <button onClick={this.numberList}>Cards</button>
        )};

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't render anything other than a button. The data ***is*** mapped, but just at the wrong place and time. The `serials` should be part of component state and rendered in the `render` method. Can you update your question to include a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not rendering anything from your component

After your process the array you should ideally set it to the state which would cause the component to re render, and if you render the serials from the state like below it will be shown once it loads. Once you click your button the numberlist function would execute and set the state with the data and it will be mapped and shown.

As per your current code you just map and return the items which is not used anywhere, so you should follow the below pattern.

```
class Serials extends Component {
  state = {
    serials: [],
  };
  numberList() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + '/serials');

    serialRef.on('value', (serial_numbers) => {
      const serials = [];
      serial_numbers.forEach((serial_number) => {
        serials.push({ s: serial_number.val() });
      });
      this.setState({ serials: serials });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.numberList}>Cards</button>
        <div>
          {this.state.serials.map((number) => (
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>{number.s.serial}</Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`serials` should be part of component state, updated by the click handler, and mapped in the `render` method.

```
state = {
  serials: [],
};

...

numberList() {
  const { user: { uid } } = this.state;
  const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serials");

  serialRef.on("value", (serial_numbers)=> {
    this.setState({
      serials: serial_numbers.map(s => ({ s: s.val() })),
    });
  });
}

...

render () {
  const { serials } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.numberList}>Cards</button>
      <div>
        {serials.map((number) => (
          <Card>
           <Card.Body>{number.s.serial}</Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )};
}
```